# Cannot access the package / the package does not exist

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am tyring to execute package given by MSDN guidelines shown below.

I get error Cannot access the package or the package does not exist.

I am trying to run this with windows authentication. Not sure what all permissions do I need to set?

I have replaced folders, paramters, projects etc with correct values related to my project.

```
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Package.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, @folder_name=N'SSIS Packages', @project_name=N'SSISPackage_ProjectDeployment', @use32bitruntime=False, @reference_id=1

Select @execution_id
DECLARE @var0 smallint = 3
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', @parameter_value=@var0

DECLARE @var1 int = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=30, @parameter_name=N'Parameter1', @parameter_value=@var1

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
GO
```

This is how this login looks in db
[image: This is how Login looks]

Comment: These are roles with their permissions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141053.aspx.  What roles have you been assigned on the server?

Comment: I have updated original post with Roles showing

Answer (score 6):

In SSMS, expand the SSIS server node in the object explorer. Look for the "Integration Services Catalogs" node. Under that you should find the database (it's an Integration Services database so it looks a bit different). Expand that and you'll find folders.

Here is the annoying part. Unless you script it out, you will have to right-click each folder and go to "properties". Under the "permissions" tab, you should find yourself or a group that you're in. If you don't, you need to get added.

THEN (you're not done)... Under each folder, you need to do the same thing (right-click properties>permissions) for each of the projects that you want to execute via script and the environments (if used) that the projects access.

If this still doesn't work for you, then you need to give yourself execute/read/write access to the SSISDB you created on the server (under the databases nodes).

Comment: For this user under SSISD Public and SSIS_Admin is check marked, and give all above permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Permissions was not a issue here. I was trying this for the first time. There was issue the way @folder_name paramter was accepted. When I deployed this projcet to SSISDB createted it was following structure. I was passing Packages as Folder_name Parameter but it was TestSSIS2014 so folder is something under projects. Then it worked.

```
SSISDB
   TestSSIS2014
     Projects
       TestSSIS2014
         Packages
          TestPackage1
           TestPackage2
```